# Create a new git repo on remote OS X Server

Tags: git, osx-server

How can I create a new git repository on remote OS X Server using command line. I know that it is possible, Xcode is able to do this when setting a new project, but I need create a new repo for a non Xcode project.

OSX client - 10.11
OSX server - 3.2.2 on 10.9.5

Answer (score 0):

Does the OS X server have a dedicated git user? I will assume yes - this will work without a dedicated git user, but I think it's useful to keep the idea of a user in mind.

1. SSH into the server as the desired user ie. `ssh git@server`
2. `cd` to the directory where you keep git repositories ie. `cd ~/repos`
3. Create a new directory here that will hold your new repository ie. `mkdir cool_project.git`
4. Initialize a new, bare, git repository in that directory: `cd cool_project.git && git init --bare`
5. You're done!

How do you commit to this repository? You can add a remote in your local repo by running:

`git remote add origin git@server:/home/git/repos/cool_project.git`

"`origin`" can be anything you like. If you change it, to say *awesome_remote*, then in order to push to this repo, you'd run `git push awesome_remote master`.

Note that anyone else that wants to use this repository has to have access to the user ie. a password or key-based access.

Comment: Does the OS X server have a dedicated git user? A: Doesn't. Xcode uses something under the hood. And SSH access is not configured on server. Only access that I have is HTTPS. I'm able to pull and push normally.

Comment: Do you have any other kind of access to the server? Remote desktop? Physical access?

Comment: Yes, I can configure directly (Physical access), configure SSH access, shared screen and so on. I have a lot of small projects on my client will be very annoying configure one by one using OS X Sever interface. If Xcode can do somehow, I can do either.